# d3 tree copy dragged node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm wondering if there's a way to alter the following tree:

http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033

So that when dragging and dropping a node into a new position, it instead copies the node rather than moving the node (ultimately would only copy if holding "shift" before/while dragging).

Take the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hvzc4uqo/1/) for example. Drag "Level 2: A" into "Level 2: B". The desired output would be now having two "Level 2: A" branches. One where it currently is on page load prior to the drag & drop, and the other as a child of "Level 2: B" which is the copy.

Desired Tree after Copy:

[image]

I have been searching and searching for examples but I can't seem to find any out there to get me pointed in the right direction.

I'm thinking that copying the node my work in a couple different places.

here..

```
.on("dragstart", function(d) {
    var d = // copy node some how here maybe?
    if (d == root) {
```

or here..

```
function initiateDrag(d, domNode) {
    //draggingNode = d; // original
    var draggingNode = // copy node some how here maybe?
```

I'm using d3v5 but any examples from earlier versions will be most helpful as well. I'm really just looking for any sort of suggestions at all, not necessarily a functional example, but obviously that would be best.

---

**UPDATE**

I have gotten a little further based off the first answer but still have yet to resolve a few outstanding issues before this works as expected. In order to better display my issues I updated the fiddle to use d3v5 and displayed any issues the best I could within the console.

Updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/y2g3qn0v/).

**Outstanding issues:**

**Issue 1**

I needed to make a copy of a node and all it's children so I decided to try out using d3's [node.copy()](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/v1.1.8/README.md#node_copy) function. This is a very nice function and is so close to what I was hoping for but the issue is that this function does not copy collapsed nodes. How could I get around this?

*Recreate using fiddle:*

Collapse "Level 2: A" and drag into "Level 2: B". Notice none of the children are copied.

**Issue 2**

When copying nodes using the node.copy() function I think I'm running into object reference issues. As stated on the node.copy() link in *Issue 1* above "The returned deep copy shares the same data". This is causing issues with generating unique node ids because if a copy of a node is updated it also updates the original node that was copied, and vice versa. How could I get around this?

*Recreate using fiddle:*

Drag "Level 2: B" into "Top Level" and click the "Save" button. Notice there are duplicate ids found.

Answer (score 1):

As the d3 is bound to data, you should use a recursive copy of dragged node, so instead of removing the node from its parent (see the lines 220-222) in your example you should add the copy to target node. 
Please have a look at [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/bL3dyqwr/) - it has hardcoded children array, but  Drag "Level 2: A" into "Level 2: B" works as you described.

```
  var copy = {
        name: draggingNode.name,
      children: [
            // todo copy children recursively
      ]
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! It has gotten me a little further but still yet have a couple issues to work out. See updates above.